# How to draw 300 lines in a circular pattern?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, gimp, ms-paint

I am trying to draw a spoke pattern with 300 spokes converging on a circle at the center in Adobe Illustrator. I would like each spoke to represent a different category at the end. And the middle circle will represent an umbrella category. I can individually draw 300 separate lines but there might be an easier and efficient way to do this. Can someone please help me? I also have GIMP, Inkscape, and Procreate if it might be easy to do on any of these softwares rather than illustrator.

Thank You,
Atindra P.

[image]

Comment: Draw one line, switch to rotate tool alt click on one end. In the dialog type 360/300 then click copy. Keep hitting ctrl+D until done.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator...

- Draw 1 vertical path
- Choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform`
- Enter "299" for the `Copies` field (you already have 1, just need 299 copies)
- Set the 9-point origin to the bottom center
- Enter "360/299" for the `Angle` Field 
  <sub>(360° of a circle's circumference divided by the number of copies you want - Illustrator does the math for you and determines the correct angle necessary in order to fit the number of desired copies)</sub> 
  [image]
- Click `OK`

If you then want access to each individual path, choose `Object > Expand Appearance`, then `Object > Ungroup`, and you are left with 300 paths around a circle converging at their center.

[image]

It takes far longer to explain this than it does to actually set it up in Illustrator.

---

<sup>Note I'm using an older version of Illustrator here. The Effect dialog window may look slightly different but the operations are the same.</sup>

Comment: Beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Since Scott has already mentioned the way I'd do it in Illustrator, here's a way to do it in Inskcape that is very similar.

Draw one line, and open up the Path Effects, hit the Plus icon and add a Rotate Copies Live Path Effect.

Set it up like this, type 300 in the number of copies, no need to set the angle, Inkscape will work it out for you.

[image]Click to see larger

If you need to create actual paths, you can bake in the Effect (equivalent to Expand in Illustrator) by doing *Path > Object to Path*

**Edit** - a slight mistake here, since I rotated around the centre axis of the line, there's actually double the amount of copies here. Set a value of 150, and you will get 300 spokes. If you set the rotation centre using the Edit Paths by nodes tool to the end point of the line instead, type in 300, you will get 300 separate lines.

Comment: @Scott Thanks.  Maybe your right, I'm not counting them though. LOL. I tried 12 and count 11 lines, so I presume it's ignoring the first copy.

Comment: @Scott - sorry I upsdated my comment while you were typing

Comment: Cool. I was curious. Sounds like Inkscape may be a bit smarter and factors the original into the copy count. Nice.

Comment: @Scott - I notice it's also a good way to generate nice interference patterns.

Comment: @Scott - yeah, I noticed that too - see the edit I made to the answer. But you can do the same in Inkscape and move the rotation point of the effect to the end point of a line. Allows you to create [all sorts of weird effects](https://imgur.com/RqOpuGU)

Comment: Yeah AI does similar, Billy -- but you *have* to create a center "dot" to rotate around... then delete the center dots after the copies are generated.

Comment: @Scott - the rotation centre is Live in Inkscape. You can drag it anywhere after applying the effect.

Comment: Well that's nice `:)` Stupid Adobe. (Your edit is what made me curious. Around center would have resulted in 600 paths in AI which *looked* like 300 because 150 paths would be overlapping the previous 150 paths - like you explained in the edit.)

Comment: @Scott you can use it for [Kaleidoscope effects too](https://imgur.com/qddTqpl).

Comment: Yeah AI will do all that, just sounds like to takes a bit more preplanning as to where the rotation point falls.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a 300 cusp star. The details in the area near the center are impossible to be shown in ordinary screens, so there's not much difference. Every line is actually forth and back, but the caused waste of space is fixed by having a thinner line.

The (double)lines can be separated by subtracting a circle which covers the uselessly dense area. To make the lines totally free the compound path must be released. That's done in the next images and one line (actually a triangle) is colored to purple:

[image]

BTW this is in Inkscape.